# How to integrate MBProgressHUD with MGTwitterEngine

Tags: iphone, xcode, twitter, mgtwitterengine, mbprogresshud

I've got both working great individually, but when I try to combine them like this:

```
- (IBAction)showWithLabel:(id)sender 
{
    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    [self.checkinsViewController.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Sending tweet";
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(tweet) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}

- (void)tweet { [_twEngine sendUpdate:@"Test tweet"]; }
```

I don't get any errors, but the tweet isn't sent If I place:

```
 [_twEngine sendUpdate:@"Test tweet"];
```

In the IBAction, it tweets. If I change tweet to sleep, the HUD shows up properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `showHUDAddedTo:animated:` and `showWhileExecuting:` methods are mutually exclusive. You can't use both methods to show the HUD .

Change your initializer to just allocate a HUD and it should work.

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
```